# select key get paired value in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a associative array as below

```
set USERS[johnh]=John Howard
set USERS[moeh]=Moe Howard
set USERS[larryk]=Lary King
```

When given johnh, it should select John Howard
When given moeh, it should give me Moe Howard

What kind of batch can do this job...

Comment: Come on a quick google search shows how arays work in batch. A simple `echo %USERS[johnh]%` displays the first array entry. The rest is just some input read and a few `if`

Comment: Thanks- I tried to use echo %USER[%johnh%]% it gave me John Howard. Now my issue is that johnh can be a variable. So I tried to set user=johnh then either echo %USER[%user%]% or !USER[%user%]!, none working

Comment: Follow @Compo's hint, use `Call Echo %%USERS[%user%]%%`

Comment: `!USER[%user%]!` should work. You remembered to enable delayed expansion first, right? Also, I have no idea how `%USER[%johnh%]%` worked for you; it shouldn't have.

Comment: This topic is fully explained at [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)...

Answer (score 0):

Other than using

```bat
Call Echo %%USERS[%~1]%%
```

or

```bat
Call Echo %%USERS[%user%]%%
```

as used in the comments, and despite your continued lack of effort, here's an example batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "USER[johnh]=John Howard"
Set "USER[moeh]=Moe Howard"
Set "USER[larryk]=Larry King"

:Askname
ClS
Set /P "Byname=Please enter your byname: "

Set "Fullname="
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('Set USER[ 2^>Nul'
) Do If /I "%%A"=="USER[%Byname%]" Set "Fullname=%%B"
If Not Defined Fullname GoTo Askname

Echo Hello %Fullname%

Pause
```

*Note: I will not be extending my answer, or answering further questions based upon it.*